# How to filter row by lowest value in a column using a for loop in R

Tags: r

This is not elegant, but for each file I want to filter the row when dvdt first meets/exceeds 15. I first filtered for each file dvdt values >= 15. Then I tried to filter rows with the minimum time value in this new data frame. The problem is that min(time) returns the global minimum across all files, whereas I'd like to identify the lowest time value within each file. Any help would be appreciated!

```
df <- structure(list(file = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("19509002.abf", "19509007.abf"
), class = "factor"), time = c(4.800000191, 4.849999905, 4.900000095, 
4.949999809, 5, 5.050000191, 5.099999905, 5.150000095, 5.199999809, 
5.25, 5.300000191, 5.349999905, 5.400000095, 5.449999809, 5.5, 
4.849999905, 4.900000095, 4.949999809, 5, 5.050000191, 5.099999905, 
5.150000095, 5.199999809, 5.25, 5.300000191, 5.349999905, 5.400000095, 
5.449999809), V = c(-34.8815918, -29.96826172, -23.65112305, 
-16.44897461, -7.843017578, 3.234863281, 15.86914063, 27.6184082, 
37.109375, 44.18945313, 49.37744141, 52.94799805, 55.41992188, 
57.00683594, 57.80029297, -36.28540039, -31.92138672, -24.78027344, 
-16.3269043, -6.683349609, 5.310058594, 18.89038086, 31.21948242, 
40.67993164, 47.24121094, 51.63574219, 54.32128906, 55.9387207
), dvdt = c(47.6074219, 98.2666016, 126.342773, 144.042969, 172.119141, 
221.557617, 252.685547, 234.985352, 189.819336, 141.601563, 103.759766, 
71.4111328, 49.4384766, 31.7382813, 15.8691406, 27.4658203, 87.2802734, 
142.822266, 169.067383, 192.871094, 239.868164, 271.606445, 246.582031, 
189.208984, 131.225586, 87.890625, 53.7109375, 32.3486328)), row.names = c(NA, 
28L), class = "data.frame")

vthresh <- data.frame()
for (i in unique(df$file)){
  vthresh = rbind(vthresh, df %>% filter(file == i, time == min(time)))
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, using `dput` or `data.frame`. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Hard to tell without any sample data,  but perhaps something like `spikes %>% group_by(file) %>% filter(dvdt >= 15) %>% slice_min(time)`

Comment: thank you for feedback, I've provided sample data for a minimal example!

Answer (score 1):

```r
# filter dvdt values >= 15
dfsub <- subset(df, dvdt >= 15)

# identify the lowest time value within each file
aggregate(dfsub$time, by = list(dfsub$file), min)
```

which gives the following output:

```
       Group.1    x
1 19509002.abf 4.80
2 19509007.abf 4.85
```

Comment: thanks that works well - if I wanted to output other row information (say V) how do I do that?

Comment: an elegant way to add the other row info would using ```merge```, as follows: ```df_sub <- subset(df, dvdt >= 15)
df_agg <- aggregate(df_sub$time, by = list(df_sub$file), min)
colnames(df_agg) <- c('file', 'time')
merge(df_agg, df_sub)```

Comment: which gives you the following output: ```          file time         V     dvdt
1 19509002.abf 4.80 -34.88159 47.60742
2 19509007.abf 4.85 -36.28540 27.46582```

Comment: sorry I have too low reputation to have my upvote recorded

Comment: I see. I thought you could flag my answer as accepted (green tick) but I am quite new here as well so maybe not an option. Anyway, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I built on Marc's answer and the code below works!

```
df_sub <- subset(df, dvdt >= 15)
df_agg <- aggregate(df_sub$time, by = list(df_sub$file), min) 
colnames(df_agg) <- c('file', 'time')
vthresh <- merge(df_sub, df_agg, by=c("file","time"))
```